# What gameplay mechanics are new to Super Smash Bros 3DS?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Are there any gameplay differences between the current Smash Bros. and Super Smash Bros. Brawl? For example, did they get rid of tripping, or is still a mechanic in Super Smash?

Comment: I purged the unnecessary comments here - we are not here to judge intent of any user. Be nice, guys, and if you can't be nice, be civil. Please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few major new/changed mechanics that we currently know of:

- Random tripping has been removed; forced tripping is still in.
- You cannot grab a character if you've thrown them in the last second (no chaingrabs).
- There is no longer a difference in edge actions upon reaching 100% damage.
- Edgehogging has been removed; instead, the incoming character will steal the edge from the current occupant.
- It appears that swimming has been removed; characters will just fall through water as in Melee.
- Directional influence has been revamped. In previous games, you could change the angle of your knockback by holding perpendicular to it. In SSB4, you instead add a vector in your holding direction, which can alter both your angle and your distance.
- Characters at high damage deal slightly more knockback.

Comment: Shields are weaker, but regenerate faster.
Perfect shield is easier to perform. (increased sweet spot)

Comment: Swimming has not been entirely removed. On some stages like Delfino Plaza (available on WiiU) you can still swim. And Vectoring was changed in some early update so its more like DI again